# Strange behavior with with writing / reading from vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I am sitting here for hours looking at the code, and I just don't get it.
It's about the **std::vector canData** which is used as a buffer for decoding and encoding data from a CAN DBC parser.
The complete example of my problem is [here.](https://bitbucket.org/tobylorenz/vector_dbc/src/8ab404018c2f7ccbf02b7d7b5953aa70ca234491/src/Vector/DBC/docs/examples/Message_Encode_Decode.cpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Basically there is a value encoded to an array and then decoded again from this array. But the size of this array is always zero and even after clearing the array, although its zero, one can still decode data from it.

Can somebody please explain that to me?
Am I missing something?

```
unsigned int canIdentifier = 0x100;
std::vector<std::uint8_t> canData;
canData.reserve(4);
network.messages[canIdentifier].signals["multiplexor"].encode(canData, 0);
network.messages[canIdentifier].signals["signal_1"].encode(canData, 0x12);

std::cout << "size: " << canData.size() << std::endl;

canData.clear();
decodeMessage(canIdentifier, canData);
std::cout << "2size: " << canData.size() << std::endl;
```

**Updated needed functions:**

```
uint64_t Signal::decode(std::vector<uint8_t> & data)
{
/* safety check */
if (bitSize == 0) {
    return 0;
}

/* copy bits */
uint64_t retVal = 0;
if (byteOrder == ByteOrder::BigEndian) {
    /* start with MSB */
    unsigned int srcBit = startBit;
    unsigned int dstBit = bitSize - 1;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bitSize; ++i) {
        /* copy bit */
        if (data[srcBit / 8] & (1 << (srcBit % 8))) {
            retVal |= (1ULL << dstBit);
        }

        /* calculate next position */
        if ((srcBit % 8) == 0) {
            srcBit += 15;
        } else {
            --srcBit;
        }
        --dstBit;
    }
} else {
    /* start with LSB */
    unsigned int srcBit = startBit;
    unsigned int dstBit = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bitSize; ++i) {
        /* copy bit */
        if (data[srcBit / 8] & (1 << (srcBit % 8))) {
            retVal |= (1ULL << dstBit);
        }

        /* calculate next position */
        ++srcBit;
        ++dstBit;
    }
}

/* if signed, then fill all bits above MSB with 1 */
if (valueType == ValueType::Signed) {
    if (retVal & (1 << (bitSize - 1))) {
        for (unsigned int i = bitSize; i < 8 * sizeof(retVal); ++i) {
            retVal |= (1ULL << i);
        }
    }
}

return retVal;
}

void Signal::encode(std::vector<uint8_t> & data, uint64_t rawValue)
{
/* safety check */
if (bitSize == 0) {
    return;
}

/* copy bits */
if (byteOrder == ByteOrder::BigEndian) {
    /* start with MSB */
    unsigned int srcBit = startBit;
    unsigned int dstBit = bitSize - 1;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bitSize; ++i) {
        /* copy bit */
        if (rawValue & (1ULL << dstBit)) {
            data[srcBit / 8] |= (1 << (srcBit % 8));
        } else {
            data[srcBit / 8] &= ~(1 << (srcBit % 8));
        }

        /* calculate next position */
        if ((srcBit % 8) == 0) {
            srcBit += 15;
        } else {
            --srcBit;
        }
        --dstBit;
    }
} else {
    /* start with LSB */
    unsigned int srcBit = startBit;
    unsigned int dstBit = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bitSize; ++i) {
        /* copy bit */
        if (rawValue & (1ULL << dstBit)) {
            data[srcBit / 8] |= (1 << (srcBit % 8));
        } else {
            data[srcBit / 8] &= ~(1 << (srcBit % 8));
        }

        /* calculate next position */
        ++srcBit;
        ++dstBit;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Oh, the joys of Undefined Behavior...  Can't say more without the code for `enccode` and `decodeMessage`.

Comment: `reserve` and `resize` are different. After calling `reserve` on a vector, the size is unchanged. A default constructed `std::vector` contains 0 elements, so `canData` will still contain 0 elements when it's used in `encode`. I assume that `encode` would expect a buffer of size greater than zero. Can't say for certain though, since you didn't share what that function does. `std::vector::reserve` is typically used to improve the performance of subsequent insertions.

Comment: `canData.reserve(4);` - I think you want `resize()` rather than `reserve()` there. `reserve()` does not give you the right to write into the reserved memory.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux code for encode/decode is [here](https://bitbucket.org/tobylorenz/vector_dbc/src/8ab404018c2f7ccbf02b7d7b5953aa70ca234491/src/Vector/DBC/Signal.cpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), basically they dereference the vector with operator[] which is ugly but is not even undefined IMO.

Comment: Providing external links to code relevant to your question is considered poor practice on Stack Overflow. Please append the relevant code to your question. One reason is that questions on SO are expected to stay up for future readers and outside resources have a tendency to mysteriously disappear (making the question useless for future readers). Another reason is that other uses do not want to have to navigate to another page or site to learn about your problem. But try to only provided the relevant snippets. Read about how to provide a helpful [MCVE].

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that's not my question (I'm not an author). Also, I must say I'm now unclear whether indexing above vector's `size()` if I know it's `reserve()`'d is defined or not.

Comment: @orhtej2 It's not ugly to use `std::vector::operator[]`, it's usually the preferred way. And it *is* undefined behavior to access an element beyond the size of a `std::vector` using `operator[]`. Since given vector's size is 0, trying to access any element is undefined behavior.

Comment: @orhtej2 My appologizes, I thought this was your question. I'll leave my comment up for the original poster, as it's still relevant to the question which links to external code. Accessing elements beyond the size of a vector is definitively undefined behavior  even if you reserved that memory.

Comment: Sorry, I added the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code step by step:

```
canData.reserve(4);
```

allocates memory for vector that can contain (at least) 4 uint8_t, but contain 0 (canData.resize(4) would change vector size). canData.capacity() is then 4 (or more), but canData.size() is 0.

encode(...) method access vector using operator[]. It does not check if index is in range (so less than canData.size()), so there is no exception (if vector at() was used instead it would throw). Also, as accessed indexes are in allocated memory, nothing bad (in particular memory leak) happens there.

```
canData.clear()
```

destroy all vector elements, that are in range, so between index 0 and canData.size(). Thus, it does not touch elements above canData.size(), which is 0 in this case. clear() also does not shrink memory allocated for vector (or is not guaranteed to reallocate to shrink memory) - shrink_to_fit() would do so.

In the end, decodeMessage operates on memory that is allocated and filled with correct data, that was not destroyed. Again, usage of vector operator[] cause no exception / memory leak.

As stated in comments, lot of undefined behavior.